# android httprequest error only in tablet

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hello I have an android application inserting data to mysql database with php. My insert code works perfect on Avd and my android phone. But it gives error on tablet. My tablet is connected to wireless internet and other parts of application works fine and getting data from json. What is the difference between devices about this error?

```
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/android3.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error error error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: what android versions do these devices run ?

Comment: Which Exception is thrown ? If it's a network error, it's probably a connectivity issue with your tablet.

Comment: Phone android 3.2, Tablet 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

This was introduced in API 11 and android allows network calls on main thread in previous versions without throwing an error.

Comment: My phone is android 3.2 and tablet is 4.1. So how can i fix this problem. Must i remove try catch?

Comment: I think i must use asynctask.

Comment: @BilalTürk Yes you should use AsyncTask